# Exclude replies from twitter streaming - tweepy

Tags: python, api, twitter, streaming, tweepy

I am pulling tweets from twitter's streaming api using tweepy. I'm then using this to autoreply to that user.

For example if I want to pull live tweets from and then reply to Donald Trump I use:

```
import tweepy
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener

import json

class StdOutListener(StreamListener):
    def on_data(self, data):
        clean_data = json.loads(data)
        tweetId = clean_data["id"]
        tweet = "YOUR MESSAGE HERE"
        respondToTweet(tweet, tweetId)

def setUpAuth():
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler("consumer_token", "consumer_secret")
    auth.set_access_token("access_token", "Access_token_secret")
    api = tweepy.API(auth)
    return api, auth

def followStream():
    api, auth = setUpAuth()
    listener = StdOutListener()
    stream = Stream(auth, listener)
    stream.filter(follow=["25073877"], is_async=True)

def respondToTweet(tweet, tweetId):
    api, auth = setUpAuth()
    api.update_status(tweet, in_reply_to_status_id=tweetId, auto_populate_reply_metadata=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    followStream()
```

If you run my above code, you'll notice it does reply to Donald Trump, but also replies to all new replies to his tweets

What do I need to add to exclude replies to his tweets from the stream?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I assume you’ve read the [automation rules for using the Twitter API](https://help.twitter.com/en/rules-and-policies/twitter-automation)

Comment: Yes - The reason I wanted to fix this was because it was generating a large amount of replies that would be considered spam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You can add a condition to only respond to tweets directly from the `follow` id.
- This should only allow a response to the account that is followed.
- So in this case, the response would be to `tweetId` only when the followed account replies.
- For multiple users, test for containment with `in`:

  - `if user_id in [25073877, id2, id3,...]:`

```py
class StdOutListener(StreamListener):
    def on_data(self, data):
        clean_data = json.loads(data)
        tweetId = clean_data["id"]
        user_id = clean_data['user']['id']
        tweet = 'Trying to figure out this code to answer a question on SO, just ignore this'
        if user_id == 25073877:
            print('Tweeting a reply now')  # optional
            respondToTweet(tweet, tweetId)
```